# ASP.NET: Trying to rename a file but getting "Access to path" denied errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

The odd thing is that something like System.IO.File.Delete() works
and the file gets deleted but will give "access to path is denied error" for .Move() operation.
All files are located in the same folder, user "Network service" has all
full control rights for the folder and all subfolders in it etc.

Folders are located in the project directory and can be seen in solution explorer.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.

```
      foreach(var info in FileActions.Where(x => x.OldSortOrder != x.SortOrder))
    {
        string FileToRename;
        string NewName;
        string OldFilePath;
        string OldFileThumbPath;


            FileToRename = info.ProductID + "/" + info.OldSortOrder + "-" + info.ImageID + ".jpg";
            NewName = info.SortOrder + "-" + info.ImageID + ".jpg";
            OldFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/"  + FileToRename);
            OldFileThumbPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/" + info.ProductID + "/thumbs/" + FileToRename);

            System.IO.File.Move(OldFilePath, NewName);
            System.IO.File.Move(OldFileThumbPath, NewName);



    }
```

Comment: did you check that the folder where you are trying to save the file is not read only and have permission to write

Comment: If its not directory permissions, then perhaps look at whether the files are readonly?

Comment: I have but I just went to check and they are set to readonly, then I unticked it again but it goes back to being readonly! I am logged in as Admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you map the path for the first files but not for the `NewName`.

So did not have the full path to know what to rename/move the file, and needs the full path to work correctly.

With out the path this is probably try to move it on the default folder of the asp.net pool that is probably don't have this permissions.

So the code will be

```
NewName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/"  
     + info.SortOrder + "-" + info.ImageID + ".jpg" );
```

and debug this lines to see if the directories and files are all correct.

Comment: That's it. Didn't know I gotta do MapPath for files that don't exist yet.

Comment: @LaserBeak The map path only adds the application path where the ~ symbol is.